# How to show combine results or export them with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm quite new in PyQGIS and I think PyQGIS could make my work easier. I first want to try with a simple code, here is what I want:
merge some features and then export them in a shapefiles.

For the combine parts, it's OK, I have this code:

```
layer=qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
geomfus = QgsGeometry.fromWkt('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY')
for elem in layer.getFeatures():
      geomfus = geom.combine(elem.geometry())
```

it is working, no problem. But now I don't know what to do to see this results in QGIS or to export the combine result in a shapefile.

Comment: the answers are in pyqgis cookbook

Comment: @LuigiPirelli no offence but your comment doesnt include a link or additional information to help the OP, its almost the equivalent to saying "the answers are on the internet"...